# Windows store apps - detect first launch of the app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I need to show a "welcome screen" (something like a license) when the user had first launched the application. This screen should be shown only once per user. Could someone guide me with this since I'm a beginner in windows development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [local storage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balsharfi/archive/2013/01/14/starting-windows-phone-development-lesson-2-of-n-access-to-application-isolated-local-storage.aspx) or [settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to store data on whether the "welcome screen" has been shown or not and use that to determine if the screen has to be shown on startup.

Comment: Not whether the welcome screen has been shown, but rather whether the license has been accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is something like LicenceInfo().
But for sure you can do it with IsolatedStorageSettings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090(v=vs.105).aspx