# first run page on wp8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

So I'm creating an app that uses Facebook and Twitter features so I want when the app is first installed to be able to run a page that allows them to setup facebook and twitter first. Like for example the Twitter setup page is TwitterSetup.xaml and FB setup is FacebookSetup.xaml. How do I code a first-run page?

Answer (score 0):

When you start the App, you need to check if the User entered the data you need (Twitter or Facebook login for example). To do this you can use [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090(v=vs.105).aspx) or [local storage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balsharfi/archive/2013/01/14/starting-windows-phone-development-lesson-2-of-n-access-to-application-isolated-local-storage.aspx) (as posted by @manojlds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838126/windows-store-apps-detect-first-launch-of-the-app/19838426#19838426)).
For example you add code in MainPage(), that loads Settings or Storage and checks if the user has already entered what you need, if not - then you navigate him to the right Page.